# AFHTTPRequestOperation setCacheResponseBlock Cannot convert value of type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, afhttprequestoperation, xcode7.1

I’m using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in swift like this :

```
let operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation? = manager.GET(requestURL, parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:AnyObject!) -> Void in

...
...
...
                success(downloadedItems: responseObject)
            }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                failure(responseFromCache: responseFromCache, error: error);
        })
```

and I’m using setCacheResponseBlock for application specific purpose (ETag etc.)

operation!.setCacheResponseBlock { (connection: NSURLConnection, cachedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse) -> NSCachedURLResponse in
            print("Returns:200")
            responseFromCache = false
            return cachedResponse
        }

Everything was OK until updating XCode to new version XCode7.1.

Here is my problem, I get this error when I build my application after update :

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLConnection, NSCachedURLResponse) -> NSCachedURLResponse' to expected argument type '((NSURLConnection!, NSCachedURLResponse!) -> NSCachedURLResponse!)!'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After checking error message I understand something wrong with my parameters. I check method’s declaration in XCode and I understand method’s declaration just updated :

```
func setCacheResponseBlock(block: ((NSURLConnection!, NSCachedURLResponse!) -> NSCachedURLResponse!)!)
```

I updated my method like this :

```
  operation!.setCacheResponseBlock { (connection: NSURLConnection!, cachedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse!) -> NSCachedURLResponse! in
            print("Returns:200")
            responseFromCache = false
            return cachedResponse
        }
```

and another happy ending with build succeeded message in Xcode. Hope this will help someone.